# Population Estimation And Conditional Probability

Tags: sampling, conditional-probability, population, density-estimation, selection-bias

Let's say that I have a data set comprised of age data for a large number of individuals, as well as a unique identifier for each individual. For terminology sake let's call this my base population. The ages are broken out into categories. Let's say that the distribution of ages in my data set are:

- **Age 0-29:** 10%
- **Age 30-49:** 30%
- **Age 50+:** 60%

Now I am given a new population of data comprised of only unique identifiers, and I want to merge this new population with my base population so that I can estimate the distribution of age categories across the new population.

Let's say that I merge the new population with the base population, and I get a match rate of ~10% (meaning that ~90% of the new population's unique identifiers were not found in the base population.) However, my population sizes are very large, so that 10% match rate contains well over a million individuals.

Among the 10% of individuals that were matched, I can now see that the distribution of age categories within that 10% is as follows:

- **Age 0-29:** 25%
- **Age 30-49:** 40%
- **Age 50+:** 35%

Here's my question: **How can I use this information to estimate the distribution of age categories of the new population from this 10% sample of matched individuals?**

The challenge I am running into is the fact that the 50+ age group is so heavily over-represented in the base data, making them much more likely to be merged to the new population. So even though ~35% of the matched sample is in the 50+ age group, it's likely that this proportion is highly inflated because this group is so heavily over-represented in the base data. I am struggling with how to estimate the true proportions of age groups in the new population given the skew present in the base data.